# Conversion of to_timestamp from Oracle to SQL Server format in Insert scripts

Tags: sql-server, oracle

My insert scripts in oracle are below format.

INSERT INTO SAMPLETABLE(CREATEDDATE) VALUES (to_timestamp ('21-MAY-20 03.36.36.000000000 PM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM'));

I want it to convert the same in SQL Server format.

Thanks for any help in advance :)

Comment: what have you tried? Have you trisome converting / casting whatever you want into timestamp?

Comment: Hi Harry, yes i tried to check with Convert by keeping datetime and datetime2 but it doesnt give complete timestamp..